# Use WordPress Site For Email List Functionality

Tags: plugins, email

I'm working on a WordPress site for my condo association. I would like to have two email aliases:

residents@mycondoplace.net

board@mycondoplace.net

that alias to all residents, and the board members respectively. Is there a WordPress plugin that would enable this functionality? Or some other service? The domain name I'm hosting my WP site on is `mycondoplace.net`.

Answer (score 0):

Email accounts are not defined by WordPress. They are defined on your hosting account. 
Since your site is hosted as a sub-part of the mycondoplace.net, you would need them to create the email accounts - and probably an email 'list'.

But, there is a way to do this (even though plugin recommendations are not generally allowed here). "Subscriber" plugins, such as [Email Subscribers & Newsletters](https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-subscribers/), will allow you to maintain a subscriber list. Each member (resident) would need to 'subscribe' to the subscriber list. You can then create 'newsletters' that you could send out to the subscriber list.

You can also set up that plugin to send out a notification email whenever a new post is published on your site.

I've used that plugin for several years, and have found it to be useful in many situations. There are other similar plugins.

Comment: I'm hosting the site via Wordpress.com's premium plan. Do they provide resources to do SMTP stuff? Not as far as I can tell.

Comment: I am not familiar with wordpress.com hosting, but believe there are limitations there. If you can add a Subscriber-type plugin to your site, then that might be the best solution for you. Otherwise, you will need to move to a non-wordpress.com hosting plan and set up a mailing list (like 'Mailman'). But a Subscriber-type plugin might be easier in either hosting case.

Answer (score 0):

You likely do not want to send emails with you're web hosting server server. Most popular e-mail providers maintain a "white list" of known trusted email providers that they allow through and put mail originating from other servers into spam without a second look.

That said, you should be able to send emails from any address (e.g. `{$something}@example.com`) you desire with a decent email provider.

Check with your email provider's docs for how to set up aliases then look into how to send emails from your WP site through them with an SMTP plugin like [Easy WP SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/) or [WP Mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/).

***Note:* You should research these plugins yourself before using them. I may recommend them at the time of writing but as time goes on, things change and I may not have updated this post to reflect that.**

Comment: The OPs issue is not 'sending' emails. He needs to address an email to residents@mycondoplace.net , and have that sent to multiple (different) recipients...like a mailing list. To do that, he needs either a 'subscriber' plugin, or a way to add a mailing list (like "MailMan") to his host. 
It wasn't clear if he had control of the hosting account he is using for his domain. If he does, then he could add something like MailMan to hist hosting account (domain) and use that as his List. That's a whole other interface to learn. A Subscriber plugin of some sort may be easier for him.

Comment: @RickHellewell I'm hosting the site via Wordpress.com. It is not my own host.